# TensorFlow 2 command "python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py" is running for TensorFlow 1 instead of TensorFlow 2 in Anaconda env

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I have TensorFlow 1.15 running in Anaconda env on my windows PC. Now I created a separate env and  I installed TensorFlow 2. When I try to run  "python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py" for TensorFlow 2 then it is looking for files in TensorFlow 1 API folder and shows no attribute 'contrib'.  I have attached a screenshot please let me know how can I solve this.
[Schreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlhiI.png)

Comment: Avoid posting your code, output, or errors in images, post it in a text format instead!

Comment: This is because tf.contrib is deprecated to use in `Tf 2.x`. This module is available to access only in `Tf 1.x`.